# display day through stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, dayofweek

I have an problem in MySQL stored procedure

table `tbl_teachers`:

```
id           dat_teacher_doj   fk_int_dept_id

1            1982-01-10          1
2            1979-09-01          1
3            1981-10-13          1
```

here i need to create an stored procedure to find out the joining date of teachers and if it is a Monday it should display Monday else it should display “Weekday” ?
i need the answer like:

call check-date (1982-01-10)
->day
weekday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just `CASE` expression with the help of `DAYNAME`

```
SELECT id, dat_teacher_doj,
       CASE DAYNAME(dat_teacher_doj) WHEN 'Monday' THEN 'Monday' ELSE 'Weekday' END
FROM   tbl_teachers
```

Procedure:this will work in `localhost phpmyadmin` as well as `workbench`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetWeekDay`(IN `paramDate` DATE)
 NO SQL 
SELECT CASE DAYNAME(paramDate) WHEN 'Monday' THEN 'Monday' ELSE 'Weekday' END AS 'WkDy'
```

Call

```
CALL `GetWeekDay`('2015-08-03');
```

Comment: can u tell me , how can i do this with stored procedure... because i wish to get the answer like: call check-date (1982-01-10) ->day weekday

Comment: we are select from DB we don't need output Parameter if we need we can pass `(out paramName  datatype)` above link will helpful for you

Comment: am not useing the php ...jest mysql !

Comment: @ashishjobish sorry for delete i have corrected my answer and reposted

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a stored procedure for this. A simple `case` expression around a [`dayofweek`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) call should do the trick:

```
SELECT id, dat_teacher_doj,
       CASE DAYOFWEEK(dat_teacher_doj) WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday' ELSE 'Weekday' END
FROM   tbl_teachers
```

Comment: can u tell me , how can i do this with stored procedure... because i wish to get the answer like:

call check-date (1982-01-10) ->day weekday

Comment: plz help me to do this.