# Stored procedure in mysql generating error while adding

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to add  the following stored procedure to my sql

```
BEGIN

declare user varchar(30);
declare amount_sent float(10,2);
declare balance float(10,2);
INSERT INTO transaction_response (ResultCode,ResultDesc,OriginatorID,TransactionID)
VALUES (ResultCode,ResultDesc,OriginatorID,TransactionID);
IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN
 select user_username into user  from send_transaction where OriginatorID = OriginatorID;
   IF FOUND_ROWS() > 0 THEN 
            select amount_in_usd into amount_sent from send_transaction where OriginatorID =  OriginatorID;
      IF FOUND_ROWS() > 0 THEN         
           select user_balance into balance  from api_users where api_username = user;
           IF FOUND_ROWS() > 0 THEN 
                    UPDATE api_users SET user_balance=user_balance-amount_sent where api_username = user;            
                    IF ROW_COUNT() = 1 THEN
                        SET statusout = '0000';
                    ELSE
                        SET statusout = '0001';
                    END IF;
            ELSE 
                SET statusout = '0002';
            END IF;
        ELSE
            SET statusout = '0003';
        END IF;             
    ELSE 
        SET status = '0004';
    END IF;
ELSE 
    SET status = '0005';
END IF;
```

END

Every time I try to add the procedure I get the following error message. I have tried to debug the statement, but I still cant find what is generating the error

```
  One or more errors occured while processing your request.
```

Comment: issue with creating stored Procedure here is code which will work for mySQL and workbech http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769551

Comment: Show full procedure code, with CREATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that because you're using [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in procedure such as `user`. Try use double quotes like `"user"`

Comment: I have tried using double quotes, I even changed 'user' to 'usssers' it still doesn't work